# How to get a local IP address in ant 1.5.1

Tags: ant, ip

I was wondering, if there is a way to figure out the local IP address with ant. I cannot use the hostinfo task, since I am bound to ant 1.5.1. Now I would write little scripts for each platform and use ant conditional mechanics to execute the appropriate script for each platform. However, maybe any of you know a more elegant way? Thanks in advance.

Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

This works on my mac running os x 10.8.2 :

```
    <target name="getCurrentIP">
        <exec executable="/usr/sbin/ipconfig" outputproperty="currentIP">
            <arg value="getifaddr"/>
            <arg value="en0"/>
        </exec>
        <echo>currentIP : ${currentIP}</echo>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<target name="checkos">
    <condition property="isWindows" value="true">
        <os family="windows" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="isLinux" value="true">
        <os family="unix" />
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="if_windows" depends="checkos" if="isWindows">
    <exec executable="cmd" outputproperty="myHostName">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="hostname"/>
    </exec>

    <exec executable="cmd" outputproperty="infraServerIPTemp" >
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="FOR /f &quot;tokens=1 delims=:&quot; %d IN ('ping ${myHostName} -4 -n 1 ^| find /i &quot;reply&quot;') DO FOR /F &quot;tokens=3 delims= &quot; %g IN (&quot;%d&quot;) DO echo infraServerIP=%g > myIP.properties"/>
    </exec>

    <property file="myIP.properties"/>
</target>

<target name="if_unix" depends="checkos" if="isLinux">
    <exec executable="hostname" outputproperty="infraServer">
        <arg line="-i"/>
    </exec>
    <property name="infraServerIP" value="${infraServer}"/>
</target>

<target name="checkOSType" depends="if_windows, if_unix"/>

<target name="do-something" depends="checkOSType">

</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of Ant addon [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) you might use :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

<!-- on windows -->
<exec executable="cmd" outputproperty="winip">
 <arg value="/c" />
 <arg value="ipconfig" />
</exec>

<!-- simple echo -->
<fl:echo>localip => #{replace('${winip}', '$2' , '\s(IP.+):\s?(\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b)')}</fl:echo>
<!-- set property -->
<fl:let>localip := replace('${winip}', '$2' , '\s(IP.+):\s?(\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b)')</fl:let>

<!-- on linux -->
<exec executable="hostname" outputproperty="linuxip">
 <arg value="-i" />
</exec>

<!-- simple echo -->
<fl:echo>localip => #{replace('${linuxip}', '$1' , '(\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b)\s(.+)')}</fl:echo>
<!-- set property -->
<fl:let>localip := replace('${linuxip}', '$1' , '(\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b)\s(.+)')</fl:let>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Without having tried it, the [requirements](http://workbench.haefelinger.it/flaka/download/manual/flaka-1.2.2.html) of Flaka state, that it will need ant 1.7.0, which in this particular case I cannot use.

Comment: OK, sorry, read over that. So i would recommend to use some scripting language (Groovy, JRuby, Javascript, Beanshell...). Catch the output with exec outputproperty and parse with script+regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution to the problem is, that we built a little Java program, which prints the local ip to the standard output. We store this output in an ant property. (We use Java instead of a scripting language of some sort, because we would otherwise have to deploy the language runtime on many systems and Java is already deployed throughout our system landscape)